# RESTful Service not working for multiple calls

Tags: wcf, web-services, jmeter

I have created a Restful Service which accepts input xml and outputs response xml. Before giving output xml it calls Web Service and gets the xml from it. I do some modifications to the xml and output it.

The client reports that when they do load testing, sometimes the response comes properly and sometimes does not from RESTful Service.

How can I do load testing with JMeter and find the loophole in it. This happens for multiple calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 great references for jmeter are:
- http://blog.milamberspace.net/ if you talk french
- http://theworkaholic.blogspot.fr/ if not

But you should definitely start by reading :
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html

Then ask questions on jmeter user list if you are stuck.
Regards
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

First create new test and save test scenario with [JMeter Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) (records user clicks in a browser).
Then use the recorded components to compose your actual test.

Don't forget to use [JMeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) (invaluable).